# 404 Issue on URLS in Sitemap (EE 1.13)

Tags: magento-enterprise, enterprise-1.13, sitemaps

Sitemaps are generating without a suffix regardless of the settings in the admin.

It appears that when enterprise_url_rewrite was written as a port from core_url_rewrite that the suffix was  missed.

Adding suffix awareness to the _getEntityUrl() function for category and product entities in the sitemap resource model seems trivial, but is there something else I am missing or is this a bug that is affecting other people?

For instance for the category (just an example see pastebin link for more info)

```
protected function _getEntityUrl($row, $entity)
{
    $url = !empty($row['request_path']) ? $row['request_path'] : 'catalog/category/view/id/' . $entity->getId();
    $suffix = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlSuffix();
    if ($suffix) {
        $url .= '.' . $suffix;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

http://pastebin.com/RPWVrhae has a bit more code.

Comment: I am getting verification this is a bug, and it seems like Kirk has the solution. But please still give us feedback on this if you are seeing it in your 1.13 installs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I verified this same issue exists on a separate project also running 1.13.1.0.

Here is a more robust version of the above for anyone implementing this as a patch. This should be applied as a proper local rewrite of Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Category and Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product, replacing instances of "category" with "product" in the latter.

- Plays safer with core code short circuiting if no suffix
- Only adds suffix to a request path. Will not add to the default url by id
- Will not add a suffix if suffix is already present - in case there is ever a situation where this happens or if you accidentally end up applying this patch on a Community Edition site, which does not have the issue.

```
protected function _getEntityUrl($row, $entity)
{
    $suffix = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlSuffix();
    if (!$suffix) {
        return parent::_getEntityUrl($row, $entity);
    }

    if (!empty($row['request_path'])) {
        $url = $row['request_path'];
        // Add suffix if not already present
        if (!preg_match('%\.[^/]+$%', $url)) {
            $url .= '.' . $suffix;
        }
    } else {
        // Don't append suffix to default URL paths
        $url = 'catalog/category/view/id/' . $entity->getId();
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: I recently discovered that enterprise_url_rewrite contains both urls with suffixes and without. The fix above will still work in this case since it only applies a suffix if one does not already exist. I have yet to determine what the intended behavior of this table is, to be honest, after discovering this. Somewhere, this is a core bug because it's causing multiple people issues with their sitemap. Whether, it's bad data in the table caused by the url migration scripts or bad logic in resource models, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

We are having the same issue for a Magento EE 1.13.0.2 site that we have just launched.  No matter what I have attempted to do, I cannot get the suffixes to be added to the sitemap.

I came with the same conclusion as you to modify the Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Category and Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product files to add on the suffix if it is set.  I am also doing a check that will only add it if the suffix is not present, so if this issue is fixed down the road somewhere else, I do not have to worry about getting extra suffixes added.

If you find a solution, please post it on here so we can figure this out.  I will post my solution as well, if I find one.

Answer (score 0):

/app/code/core/Enterprise/Catalog/Helper/Category/UrlRewrite.php:

In `joinTableToSelect()`

This line

`'default_urc.category_id = url_rewrite_category.category_id AND default_urc.store_id = 0',`

should be:

`'default_urc.category_id = main_table.entity_id AND default_urc.store_id = 0',`

NOTE the main_table.entity_id reference instead.